# How to suppress valgrind warnings from gpgme?

Tags: c, valgrind, gpgme

I'm trying to use GPGME in my code to verify some signatures. However, simply initializing and releasing the GPGME contexts causes valgrind to spew a large number of warnings.

For example:

```
#include <gpgme.h>

int main() {
    gpgme_check_version(NULL);
    gpgme_ctx_t my_ctx;
    gpgme_error_t gpg_err;

    gpg_err = gpgme_new(&my_ctx);

    gpgme_release(my_ctx);

    return 0;
}
```

Compile this with `gcc -lgpgme -lassuan -lgpg-error main.c` and then run it under valgrind. From `valgrind -v ./a.out`, it seems like this code starts 6 different processes. I've copied the relevant warning messages:

```
==19158== Warning: invalid file descriptor 1024 in syscall close()
==19158==    at 0x558DBC4: close (in /usr/lib/libc-2.26.so)
==19158==    by 0x4E65DF8: ??? (in /usr/lib/libgpgme.so.11.19.0)
==19158==    by 0x4E66D65: ??? (in /usr/lib/libgpgme.so.11.19.0)
==19158==    by 0x4E6736B: ??? (in /usr/lib/libgpgme.so.11.19.0)
==19158==    by 0x4E56572: gpgme_get_engine_info (in /usr/lib/libgpgme.so.11.19.0)
==19158==    by 0x4E56C87: ??? (in /usr/lib/libgpgme.so.11.19.0)
==19158==    by 0x4E6838F: gpgme_new (in /usr/lib/libgpgme.so.11.19.0)
==19158==    by 0x10880B: main (in /home/thedoctor/Programming/gpgmetest/mytest)
==19158== Warning: invalid file descriptor 1025 in syscall close()
==19158==    at 0x558DBC4: close (in /usr/lib/libc-2.26.so)
==19158==    by 0x4E65DF8: ??? (in /usr/lib/libgpgme.so.11.19.0)
==19158==    by 0x4E66D65: ??? (in /usr/lib/libgpgme.so.11.19.0)
==19158==    by 0x4E6736B: ??? (in /usr/lib/libgpgme.so.11.19.0)
==19158==    by 0x4E56572: gpgme_get_engine_info (in /usr/lib/libgpgme.so.11.19.0)
==19158==    by 0x4E56C87: ??? (in /usr/lib/libgpgme.so.11.19.0)
==19158==    by 0x4E6838F: gpgme_new (in /usr/lib/libgpgme.so.11.19.0)
==19158==    by 0x10880B: main (in /home/thedoctor/Programming/gpgmetest/mytest)
==19158== Warning: invalid file descriptor 1026 in syscall close()
==19158==    at 0x558DBC4: close (in /usr/lib/libc-2.26.so)
==19158==    by 0x4E65DF8: ??? (in /usr/lib/libgpgme.so.11.19.0)
==19158==    by 0x4E66D65: ??? (in /usr/lib/libgpgme.so.11.19.0)
==19158==    by 0x4E6736B: ??? (in /usr/lib/libgpgme.so.11.19.0)
==19158==    by 0x4E56572: gpgme_get_engine_info (in /usr/lib/libgpgme.so.11.19.0)
==19158==    by 0x4E56C87: ??? (in /usr/lib/libgpgme.so.11.19.0)
==19158==    by 0x4E6838F: gpgme_new (in /usr/lib/libgpgme.so.11.19.0)
==19158==    by 0x10880B: main (in /home/thedoctor/Programming/gpgmetest/mytest)
==19158== Warning: invalid file descriptor 1027 in syscall close()
==19158==    Use --log-fd=<number> to select an alternative log fd.
==19158==    at 0x558DBC4: close (in /usr/lib/libc-2.26.so)
==19158==    by 0x4E65DF8: ??? (in /usr/lib/libgpgme.so.11.19.0)
==19158==    by 0x4E66D65: ??? (in /usr/lib/libgpgme.so.11.19.0)
==19158==    by 0x4E6736B: ??? (in /usr/lib/libgpgme.so.11.19.0)
==19158==    by 0x4E56572: gpgme_get_engine_info (in /usr/lib/libgpgme.so.11.19.0)
==19158==    by 0x4E56C87: ??? (in /usr/lib/libgpgme.so.11.19.0)
==19158==    by 0x4E6838F: gpgme_new (in /usr/lib/libgpgme.so.11.19.0)
==19158==    by 0x10880B: main (in /home/thedoctor/Programming/gpgmetest/mytest)
==19158== Warning: invalid file descriptor 1028 in syscall close()
==19158==    at 0x558DBC4: close (in /usr/lib/libc-2.26.so)
==19158==    by 0x4E65DF8: ??? (in /usr/lib/libgpgme.so.11.19.0)
==19158==    by 0x4E66D65: ??? (in /usr/lib/libgpgme.so.11.19.0)
==19158==    by 0x4E6736B: ??? (in /usr/lib/libgpgme.so.11.19.0)
==19158==    by 0x4E56572: gpgme_get_engine_info (in /usr/lib/libgpgme.so.11.19.0)
==19158==    by 0x4E56C87: ??? (in /usr/lib/libgpgme.so.11.19.0)
==19158==    by 0x4E6838F: gpgme_new (in /usr/lib/libgpgme.so.11.19.0)
==19158==    by 0x10880B: main (in /home/thedoctor/Programming/gpgmetest/mytest)
==19158== Warning: invalid file descriptor 1029 in syscall close()
==19158==    at 0x558DBC4: close (in /usr/lib/libc-2.26.so)
==19158==    by 0x4E65DF8: ??? (in /usr/lib/libgpgme.so.11.19.0)
==19158==    by 0x4E66D65: ??? (in /usr/lib/libgpgme.so.11.19.0)
==19158==    by 0x4E6736B: ??? (in /usr/lib/libgpgme.so.11.19.0)
==19158==    by 0x4E56572: gpgme_get_engine_info (in /usr/lib/libgpgme.so.11.19.0)
==19158==    by 0x4E56C87: ??? (in /usr/lib/libgpgme.so.11.19.0)
==19158==    by 0x4E6838F: gpgme_new (in /usr/lib/libgpgme.so.11.19.0)
==19158==    by 0x10880B: main (in /home/thedoctor/Programming/gpgmetest/mytest)
```

The exact same set of warnings is repeated for 6 different processes in total. It seems like GPGME tries to close some file descriptors that is doesn't own.

My question is twofold:

1. Am I using the gpgme API wrong? Is there something else I need to do?
2. If the usage of the API is correct, how can I suppress these warnings from valgrind?

I can't seem to get valgrind to produce suppressions for these warnings. Running `valgrind --gen-suppressions=all -v ./a.out` doesn't show any suppressions in the output. I guess that is because these are warnings and not real errors. I tried writing a suppression myself, but I'm not sure what the type should be. Usually, when I have had to write suppressions, they are for `Memcheck:Leak`. But what category do these warnings fall into?

EDIT: Here is a suppression I tried writing:

```
{
    gpgme-leak-fd
    fun:close
    ...
    fun:gpgme_new
}
```

EDIT 2: I tried to put a bounty, but it expired. If you have a valid answer for this, I offer a bounty of 100 rep.

Comment: You can write your own suppressions. See  https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Valgrind_Suppression_File_Howto

Comment: Like I mentioned, I have already tried to do that. But valgrind doesn't seem to honor those. Probably because my syntax is incorrect

Answer (score 0):

Here are some rules for GPGME written by Dan McGee, taken from [here](http://archlinux.2023198.n4.nabble.com/PATCH-1-2-valgrind-supp-add-known-leak-exposed-by-cURL-td3596934.html):

```
{
   gpgme-static-get-engine-info
   Memcheck:Leak
   fun:malloc
   ...
   fun:gpgme_get_engine_info
}
{
   gpgme-static-set-engine-info
   Memcheck:Leak
   fun:malloc
   ...
   fun:_gpgme_set_engine_info
   fun:gpgme_set_engine_info
}
{
   gpgme-static-set-locale
   Memcheck:Leak
   fun:malloc
   fun:strdup
   fun:gpgme_set_locale
}
```

Comment: As I mentioned in my post, it's not the memleaks that I am trying to suppress, but rather the invalid file descriptor warnings.